# Not able to replicate acra database in couch db

Tags: android, couchdb, acra, acralyzer

In this [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-and-use-acra-android/en)
I am able to follow till the _utils is accessible remotely. But when trying to follow further for replicating the database from remote to local using `http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage` in the remote and in local providing acra-{myappname} and clicking on replicate button i am getting following error in the log file.

```
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:16:59 GMT] [info] [<0.6274.2>] Retrying HEAD request to http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage/ in 0.25 seconds due to error {code,503}
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:00 GMT] [info] [<0.6274.2>] Retrying HEAD request to http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage/ in 0.5 seconds due to error {code,503}
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:01 GMT] [info] [<0.6274.2>] Retrying HEAD request to http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage/ in 1.0 seconds due to error {code,503}
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:02 GMT] [info] [<0.6274.2>] Retrying HEAD request to http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage/ in 2.0 seconds due to error {code,503}
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:04 GMT] [info] [<0.6274.2>] Retrying HEAD request to http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage/ in 4.0 seconds due to error {code,503}
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:08 GMT] [info] [<0.6274.2>] Retrying HEAD request to http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage/ in 8.0 seconds due to error {code,503}
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:16 GMT] [info] [<0.6274.2>] Retrying HEAD request to http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage/ in 16.0 seconds due to error {code,503}
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:28 GMT] [info] [<0.4423.2>] 182.74.124.122 - - POST /_replicate 500
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:28 GMT] [error] [<0.6275.2>] ** Generic server <0.6275.2> terminating 
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.6274.2>,killed}
** When Server state == {state,"http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage/",
                               20,[],[],
                               {[],[]}}
** Reason for termination == 
** killed

[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:28 GMT] [error] [<0.6275.2>] {error_report,<0.34.0>,
                      {<0.6275.2>,crash_report,
                       [[{initial_call,
                          {couch_replicator_httpc_pool,init,['Argument__1']}},
                         {pid,<0.6275.2>},
                         {registered_name,[]},
                         {error_info,
                          {exit,killed,
                           [{gen_server,terminate,6,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,744}]},
                            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},
                         {ancestors,
                          [<0.6274.2>,couch_replicator_job_sup,
                           couch_primary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.35.0>]},
                         {messages,[]},
                         {links,[]},
                         {dictionary,[]},
                         {trap_exit,true},
                         {status,running},
                         {heap_size,376},
                         {stack_size,27},
                         {reductions,526}],
                        []]}}
[Thu, 08 Oct 2015 05:17:28 GMT] [error] [<0.4423.2>] httpd 500 error response:
 {"error":"timeout"}
```

Comment: I've got the same issue today. I have working acralyzer with one app and now i need to add another one. Same error when attempting to replicate in Cloudant interface.

Comment: @Евгений Кравцов did you solve the issue?

Comment: Nope) I've successfuly replicate database about month ago with this link - http://get.acralyzer.com/distrib-acra-storage - and now it just don't work. I think its server problem, not mine, because 503 error. I will w8 sometime and if error won't resolve - i'll just switch to email notification.

Or maybe they change query for replication - but i checked the website and didn't find something about that.

By the way, my current acralyzer works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its not working with the futon UI follow the following link 
[here](https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer/wiki/manual-setup). Note: For Cloning the project as suggested in the link just download the zip file and extract it and follow the further instructions.